# Custom Listview Adapter, adding a static footer, and understanding R.id.list

Tags: android, listview, sticky-footer

There is something I'm just not getting, and I'm looking for assistance in understanding what is happening here.

I have a custom list adapter (that just extends BaseAdapter) that I have successfully been using to generate and display a list. Now I want to add a static footer to the bottom of my list. After looking at a number of resources (specifically [this one)](http://blog.maxaller.name/2010/05/attaching-a-sticky-headerfooter-to-an-android-listview/) I've come to realize that my reluctance of using XML has to come to an end, and set up the following xml layout in a file called devices_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/bottom_control_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/bottom_control_toggle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textOff="Filter Favourites OFF" 
        android:textOn="Filter Favourites ON"/>
</LinearLayout>
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip" 
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_control_bar">
</ListView>
<TextView android:id="@android:id/empty" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/main_empty_list"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_control_bar"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

After some adjustments to the activity that holds the list, I ran the code. I see my footer, (and also the tab widget which is parent to everything), but the area where the list goes is empty.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       this.setContentView(R.layout.devices_list);

       db = new DbManager(this);
       db.open();

       AllCur = db.fetchAllDevices();
       startManagingCursor(AllCur);

       list = new DeviceListAdapter(this, AllCur);   //make my custom list adapter                  
       setListAdapter(list);
            }
```

Is there some way to link up the ListView widget declared in my xml with my DeviceListAdapter? It's pretty clear to me now that I'm not entirely sure about how this is all working. Any help in clarification would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've run into similar issues a while ago, and my adapter was causing the issue. Try the listview and display first against an xml array defined as resource, that should display just fine.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are suggesting here - if I have an xml array then it doesn't really help me as I want to use my custom array adapter which is using a cursor I supply it.
For funsies, I put the XML I have been trying to make work into the Notepad example (which uses the SimpleCursorAdapter and a couple of XML arrays) and my footer appeared no problem. So based on that, do you have any hints about how your adapter was causing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have both the `ListView` and the `TextView` set to `android:layout_above="@id/bottom_control_bar"`, which means the `TextView` will overlap the `ListView`. And, you have said that your `ListView` height is `0dip`, which will make for an extremely short list.

I would define the `ListView` as being above the `TextView` and anchored to the top of the screen (`android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`).

> Is there some way to link up the
>   ListView widget declared in my xml
>   with my DeviceListAdapter?

You already are, by calling `setListAdapter()`.

Comment: aha! The android:layout_alignParentTop="true" is what did it. I went back to my example, surprised that I missed that, and realized it was never there. I think it is because the example I followed places the list between a header and a footer, while I am simply placing mine above a footer. The height of the ListView doesn't seem to matter once the alignment to the parent is set.